# Find count for function

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a function that checks another function for a count, if the count is nothing then I want it to set an alert.

This is the counting function

```
    function agentn_load($agentid)
{
    $dbh = dbh_get();

    $sql = 'count a.* ' .
             'from transfer a ' .
            'where a.agent_id = ?';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $r = $stmt->fetch();

    dbh_free($dbh);

    return $agentn;
}
```

This is supposed to reference it

```
$agentn = agentn_load($tran['agent_id']);
$agentNumber = false;
if (empty($alertLevel)) {
    if ($agentn > 0) {
        $alertLevel = 'high';
        $alertText = 'Agent Receipt number already in use';
        $agentNumber = true;
    }
}
if ($agentNumber) {
    $mailTo = 'xxx@gmail.com';
    $mailFrom = 'alert@this.com';
    $mailSubject = 'Agent receipt number already in use';
    $mailBody = 'Hello,' . "\n" .
                "\n" .
                'This transfer agent receipt number is already in use' . "\n" .
                "\n";

    $mailHeaders = 'Cc: ' . $mailCc . "\n" .
                   'From: ' . $mailFrom;
    mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailBody, $mailHeaders);
}
```

But I can't get it working

Comment: you no where called your function `agentn_load()` anywhere in your posted code.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie how do I do that? I have this eight at the top of the second function $agentn = agentn_load($tran['agent_id']);

Comment: @Kilisi so what is not working ?

Comment: The `$agentn` you return from the function is not assigned to. Moreover, the SQL statement in the function is syntactically incorrect (it should be `count(*)`). Obviously you are ignoring exceptions somewhere.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer it's not returning a count I think, or it's returning a count but it's not being used.